getInitialNotification returns null for SFMC notification
I have implemented "react-native-marketingcloudsdk": "^8.1.0" SDK into our React Native 0.65.0 app. We have Firebase messaging also along with SFMC. Earlier notification was not getting displayed in the systerm trey when the app was in background and killed state. Although Firebase notification callbacks were getting called. To fix this issue, I added NotificationService.java like below and after that notification started appearing in the trey.
public class NotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public NotificationService() {}

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/multiple-push-sdks.html
        if (PushMessageManager.isMarketingCloudPush(remoteMessage)){
            //handle Marketing Cloud
            MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk((marketingCloudSdk -> marketingCloudSdk.getPushMessageManager().handleMessage(remoteMessage)));
        } else {
            //firebase will handle this by default
        }
    }
}

And added this in AndroidManifest.xml as below,
        <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".NotificationService" android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="100">
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

Now the issue I am facing is, when the app is in killed state and I sent SFMC push, I am getting the notification in the trey but when I open the app tapping on the notification then the 'getInitialNotification' function returning null.
All the other Firebase messaging callbacks are working fine except getInitialNotification. If I sent the notification from Firebase or https://www.pushtry.com/ in the killed state and opening the app from Notification, in this case I am getting the data in getInitialNotification. Its not working only in case of SFMC push notification. I tried many combination but not able to getting it working. Can anyone please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance!.
Few more details,
I am calling SFMCSdk.configure in onCreate function.
